# Prompt to enter name into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm planning to create a JavaScript prompt where you can enter your name and it will go to the 's value. How can I make the code work? I tried the below code but it seems it needed a jQuery 1.7.1

```
function getName() {
    do {
        var name=prompt("Please enter your CLAM username");
    }
    while(name.length < 4);
    $('#myinput').val(name);
}

getName();
```

HTML

```
<input id="myinput"/>
```

I expect the output to be `<input id="myinput" value"name from prompt">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('myinput').val(name);
```

is for jquery only. if you don't want to use jquery then use this

```
document.getElementById('myinput').value = name;
```

for a pure javascript..

Here is my answer for this.

```
<input id="myinput"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getName() {
    do {
        var name=prompt("Please enter your CLAM username");
    }
    while(name.length < 4);
    document.getElementById('myinput').value = name;
}
getName();
    </script>
```

note: don't put your `<input id="myinput"/>` at the bottom or else you will get null. put it above the script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need jQuery for this:

```js
function getName() {
  do {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your CLAM username");
  }
  while (name.length < 4);
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = name;
}

getName();
```

```html
<input id="myinput" />
```

If you really want to use jQuery, then import a newer version:

```js
function getName() {
  do {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your CLAM username");
  }
  while (name.length < 4);
  $("#myinput").val(name);
}

getName();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input id="myinput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the line of code `$('#myinput').val(name)` is jquery syntax.

You can change it to javascript by

```
document.getElementById('myinput').value = name;
```

it is equal with `$('#myinput').val(name);`

```js
function getName() {
    do {
        var name=prompt("Please enter your CLAM username");
    }
    while(name.length < 4);
    document.getElementById('myinput').value = name;
}

getName();
```

```html
<input id="myinput"/>
```